# Parsing XML with scala not working

Tags: xml, parsing, scala

Here is the XML that I am trying to parse:

```
val response = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><createCustomerProfileResponse xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns=\"AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd\"><messages><resultCode>Error</resultCode><message><code>E00039</code><text>A duplicate record with ID 8386840 already exists.</text></message></messages><customerPaymentProfileIdList /><customerShippingAddressIdList /><validationDirectResponseList><string>1,1,1,This transaction has been approved.,0GR6L8,Y,2173844354,none,Test transaction for ValidateCustomerPaymentProfile.,0.00,CC,auth_only,,Test21,Rasmussen,,1234 test st,San Diego,CA,92107,,,,,none,none,none,none,none,none,none,none,0.00,0.00,0.00,FALSE,none,163C552C4DDDC440BAA35C76C47EB79D,,2,,,,,,,,,,,XXXX0027,Visa,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,</string></validationDirectResponseList></createCustomerProfileResponse>"
```

Here is my code:

```
val source = Source.fromString(response)
val html = new HTML5Parser
val htmlObject = html.loadXML(source)

var resultCode = (htmlObject \ "createCustomerProfileResponse" \ "messages" \ "resultCode").text
```

resultCode is always empty. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I updated the response XML. Now it only has one root XML. It still doesn't work.

I also changed the html5Parser from models.html5Parser to just html5Parser. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure that XML is valid, is it ? If you check it, it has 2 root processing instructions followed by root elements. It looks like 2 docs concatenated.

Comment: `error: not found: value models` -- you need to clarify which library you imply (`HTML5Parser`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of you structure is already implicit (`createCustomerProfileResponse`) so yo don't need to select it.

This should work:

```
var resultCode = (htmlObject \ "messages" \ "resultCode").text
```